# Call a Nan Value and change to a number in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, say `df`, which looks like this:

```
id            property_type1  property_type  pro
1               Condominium              2    2
2                      Farm             14   14
3                     House              7    7
4                 Lots/Land             15   15
5  Mobile/Manufactured Home             13   13
6              Multi-Family              8    8
7                 Townhouse             11   11
8             Single Family             10   10
9                 Apt/Condo              1    1
10                      Home             7    7
11                       NaN             29  NaN
```

Now, I need the `pro` column to have the same value as the `property_type` column, whenever the `property_type1` column has a `NaN` value. This is how it should be:

```
id            property_type1  property_type  pro
1               Condominium              2    2
2                      Farm             14   14
3                     House              7    7
4                 Lots/Land             15   15
5  Mobile/Manufactured Home             13   13
6              Multi-Family              8    8
7                 Townhouse             11   11
8             Single Family             10   10
9                 Apt/Condo              1    1
10                      Home             7    7
11                       NaN             29  29
```

That is, in line 11, where `property_type1` is `NaN`, the value of the `pro` column becomes 29, which is the value of `property_type`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ix` is deprecated, don't use it.

**Option 1**
I'd do this with `np.where` -

```
df = df.assign(pro=np.where(df.pro.isnull(), df.property_type, df.pro))
df
    id            property_type1  property_type   pro
0    1               Condominium              2   2.0
1    2                      Farm             14  14.0
2    3                     House              7   7.0
3    4                 Lots/Land             15  15.0
4    5  Mobile/Manufactured Home             13  13.0
5    6              Multi-Family              8   8.0
6    7                 Townhouse             11  11.0
7    8             Single Family             10  10.0
8    9                 Apt/Condo              1   1.0
9   10                      Home              7   7.0
10  11                       NaN             29  29.0
```

---

**Option 2**
If you want to perform in-place assignment, use `loc` -

```
m = df.pro.isnull()
df.loc[m, 'pro'] = df.loc[m, 'property_type']
df

    id            property_type1  property_type   pro
0    1               Condominium              2   2.0
1    2                      Farm             14  14.0
2    3                     House              7   7.0
3    4                 Lots/Land             15  15.0
4    5  Mobile/Manufactured Home             13  13.0
5    6              Multi-Family              8   8.0
6    7                 Townhouse             11  11.0
7    8             Single Family             10  10.0
8    9                 Apt/Condo              1   1.0
9   10                      Home              7   7.0
10  11                       NaN             29  29.0
```

Compute the mask just once, and use it to index multiple times, which should be more efficient than computing it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Find the rows where `property_type1` column is `NaN`, and for those rows: assign the `property_type` values to the `pro` column.

```
df.ix[df.property_type1.isnull(), 'pro'] = df.ix[df.property_type1.isnull(), 'property_type']
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `ix`, it's deprecated. 2. Don't compute the mask twice, it's inefficient.

Comment: No problem @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, you are right. I am not up to date with `ix`, and double-typing the mask is my mistake.

Comment: As long as you understand, that's awesome. I don't know who downvoted, but I've made up for it with an upvote. Good luck!